# How to scan/log already running processes on Unix

Tags: unix, process, debug

you can use `ps` to list running processes, but I would like to know if there is a way to *inspect* the running processes to any level of detail. for example, maybe there is a way to see every assembly instruction it invokes, or every change it makes to the file system or global memory. these are processes i don't directly invoke or control.

Comment: Look into strace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach a debugger such as `gdb` to any running process.
stop it and single step it etc

If you have the source and debug table you can set breakpoints at lines instated of just a public functions. I have not tried to used gdb with a dissassembly.
.